# How to insert an XML with more than 4000 Characters into an XMLTYPE Column in Mule

Tags: mule, dataweave

I Have an XML which have more than 4000 Characters . The Datatype in Oracle in XMLTYPE . The Insert or Execute Script Components are not allowing me to insert this XML into Oracle . I Cannot Change the Datatype in Oracle . Is there any way i can insert the XML into XMLTYPE Column. In Java i am able to achieve it by creating and SQLXML object from Connection .

```
SQLXML xml = conn.createSQLXML(); //This allowing to save the xml at any size
```

Error i am getting

```
ORA-01461: can bind a LONG value only for insert into a LONG column
```

insert Statement

```
insert into ABC(ID,RESPONSE_XML) values(123, :RESPONSE_XML))
```

Transformation

```
'RESPONSE_XML' : write(payload, 'application/xml')
```

If i reduce the number characters in the payload xml its inserting successfully . What we can do here to get it inserted.
JDBC Driver i am using is ojdbc14-10g.jar[image]

Comment: Please add the complete error when you try to insert more than 4000 characters, and the DDL of the field.

Comment: The table definition is still missing. The error should include the full error message from Mule. You should share the complete mule operations and transformations from the flow as XML, not just partial snippets

Comment: In addition to my last comment, also include the name and version of the JDBC driver and the Database connector configuration.

Answer (score 0):

it could be an Oracle limitation. It has a limit on the size of XML identifiers:

> XML Identifier Length Limit – Oracle XML DB supports only XML identifiers that are 4000 characters long or shorter.

https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E18283_01/appdev.112/e16659/appjspec.htm

Having an XML like that would be just insane.

Comment: But is it really a limitation in Oracle or Mule . Because in In java we are able to achieve it using  SQLXML xml = conn.createSQLXML(); This allowing to save the xml at any size .So there should be such an option in mule as well right ?

Comment: That's information you should provide in the question.